# Swap view for spinner

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Given the following...

```
<StackLayout>
   <ActivityIndicator VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="activityIndicator" Color="Red" IsRunning="true" />
   <label>
</StackLayout>
```

I want to show the label and hide the activity indicator or vica versa. How can I make the activity indicator take up the same height as the label without having to worry about measuring the height of the label?

Comment: I don't have a way of testing right now, but could you set the BindingContext of the ActivityIndicator to the Label, then bind the HeightRequest to the labels Height? Maybe even bind the visibility too with a converter to swap the visibilty when the label is shown or hidden.

Comment: @NigelFerrissey Seems to work. Thanks.